What's the difference between Ref and AtomicCell of Cats Effect 3?
In Cats Effect 3, they provides concurrent primitives like Ref and AtomicCell. But I'm not sure about different between two.
When we need AtomicCell instead of Ref? What features do they have? What features does lack one?

Let's start by comparing the APIs:
Ref defines methods like:
def access: F[(A, (A) => F[Boolean])]
def modify[B](f: (A) => (A, B)): F[B]
def modifyState[B](state: State[A, B]): F[B]
def set(a: A): F[Unit]
def tryModify[B](f: (A) => (A, B)): F[Option[B]]
def tryModifyState[B](state: State[A, B]): F[Option[B]]
def tryUpdate(f: (A) => A): F[Boolean]
def update(f: (A) => A): F[Unit]
// and methods build on top of them

These methods require us to provide a pure function to modify state, or only read/write a value from it. It's like a safer version of var.
AtomicCell defines methods like:
def evalGetAndUpdate(f: (A) => F[A]): F[A]
def evalModify[B](f: (A) => F[(A, B)]): F[B]
def evalUpdate(f: (A) => F[A]): F[Unit]
def evalUpdateAndGet(f: (A) => F[A]): F[A]
def get: F[A]
def modify[B](f: (A) => (A, B)): F[B]
def set(a: A): F[Unit]
// and methods build on top of them

It allows updating state with a method working on F - that is your state can be updated with a side effect. So it's like a safer:

private var a: A

def update(f: A => A): A = synchronized {
  a = f(a)
}

Why it matters? The docs tells us why:

The AtomicCell can be treated as a combination of Mutex and Ref:
import cats.effect.{IO, Ref}
import cats.effect.std.Mutex

trait State
class Service(mtx: Mutex[IO], ref: Ref[IO, State]) {
  def modify(f: State => IO[State]): IO[Unit] = 
    mtx.lock.surround {
      for {
        current <- ref.get
        next <- f(current)
        _ <- ref.set(next) 
      } yield ()
    }
}

The following is the equivalent of the example above:
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.effect.std.AtomicCell

trait State class Service(cell: AtomicCell[IO, State]) {
  def modify(f: State => IO[State]): IO[Unit] = 
    cell.evalUpdate(current => f(current)) }


In other words:

Ref is "leaner", but it's only convenient to use if it's something that does not require "transactions" and there is no risk of breaking things with concurrent access (e.g. thread 1 reads and starts blocking computation, thread 2 reads and starts blocking computations, thread 2 writes, threads 1 writes... 1 update has been lost!)
AtomicCell is blocking new updates until the started one is done (thread 1 reads and starts long computation, thread 2 tries to read... and has to wait, thread 1 finishes, thread 2 can read value...), so it should be safer to use but mutex might introduce some overhead

I'd probably prefer Ref for things processed in a single Fiber, or for things where concurrent update is very unlikely (e.g. changing some global flags with admin commands). Or for simple mocks during testing and prototyping.
I'd pick up AtomicCell when I would have to keep state in memory while treating it like a simple "in memory database" with some transactionality but not necessarily persistence (similar use case to STM but here we're allowing side effects, so retries are off the table).

Also worth pointing out that they both approach the problem of concurrent modifications from different angles: "optimistic" VS "pessimistic" locking. Curiously someone asked the same question on Discord a couple of days ago, and Daniel provided a great answer: https://discord.com/channels/632277896739946517/632278585700384799/1272675032736469013

TL;DR; it is usually better to prefer Ref unless you really need the power of AtomicCell; i.e. you do need exclusive access or the operations you are doing are expensive enough that the cost of the lock is minimal, and repeating them in a CAS loop would be worse or incorrect.

Thanks for your answer! So you mean Ref assumes modify operation is pure (value is computed instantly; so it does not acquire lock), but AtomicCell assumes modify operation is not pure (it can be interrupted by other fiber; so it acquires lock)?

@Windymelt Ref assumes your update operation can be safely retried multiple times. And it will retry it multiple times in case of contention. AtomicCell ensures the operation runs only once but it needs a lock for that.
